# How to add custom commands in Dockerfile for sbt plugin

Tags: scala, docker, sbt

When I do `sbt docker:publishLocal`, it creates a Dockerfile automatically erasing previous content of the file.

I wanted to add custom commands to add cassandra to the container. I copy pasted the content of this file

https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/blob/064fb4e2682bf9c1909e4cb27225fa74862c9086/3.11/Dockerfile

and tried to run above command again. But that wipes out all existing content and replace it with default content.

How can I add docker commands in Dockerfile or build.sbt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sbt-docker plugin has a customization section, [including one "Write from Scratch"](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html#write-from-scratch), which could be of interest:

> You can simply wipe out all docker commands with

```
dockerCommands := Seq()
```

> Now let’s start adding some Docker commands.

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker._

dockerCommands := Seq(
  Cmd("FROM", "openjdk:8"),
  Cmd("LABEL", s"""MAINTAINER="${maintainer.value}""""),
  ExecCmd("CMD", "echo", "Hello, World from Docker")
)
```

You can write your custom Dockerfile that way: it will be correctly regenerated.

> How am I going to add something like this:

```
 RUN set -x \ 
     && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \ 
     && wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu....
```

As in the example [from the documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html#add-commands):

```
ExecCmd("RUN",
    "set", "-x",
     "&&",
     "apt-get", "update", ...
),
```

Comment: How am I going to add something like this:
RUN set -x \
 && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
 && wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu....

Comment: @SujitBaniya I have edited the answer to address your comment